# Creating custom List View with two TextViews

Tags: android, listview

I tried to create my own listview using this example http://www.thepcwizard.in/2012/09/android-creating-custom-listview-for.html 
Also I checked that my feed and message classes work perfectly.

customadapter.xml:

```
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/textView1"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/textView2"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    </LinearLayout>
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
package ***;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import ***;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<RssMessage> _data;
    Context _c;

    CustomAdapter(ArrayList<RssMessage> data, Context c) {
        _data = data;
        _c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("here","here");
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) _c
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.customadapter, null);
        }

        TextView fromView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView subView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        RssMessage msg = _data.get(position);


        fromView.setText(msg.getTitle());
        subView.setText(msg.getPUBDATE());

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _data.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
}
```

usage of customadapter

```
ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(feed.getMessages() , this));
```

log

```
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.ayratbadykov.rssunion/ru.ayratbadykov.rssunion.ArticleListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at ru.ayratbadykov.rssunion.ArticleListActivity.onCreate(ArticleListActivity.java:55)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-31 18:29:23.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1227):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: The stack trace says the exception is occurring in `ArticleListActivity.onCreate()` on line 55, not your adapter.

Comment: Karakuri, line 55 is setting Adapter to listview (lv.setAdapter). Maybe I implement this method wrong?

Comment: Then something in this line is causing a null pointer exception: `lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(feed.getMessages() , this));` Have you checked that `lv` and `feed` are not null?

Comment: Feed is definitely not null. And ListView is described in xml file , so I don't think it's null

Comment: You should set a break point and check with a debugger. `findViewById()` can return null if for some reason it doesn't find the view. It would help if you post the code for the `ArticleListActivity` and its layout.

Comment: Karakuri, you were right! Listview was actually null. I was using wrong layout.Thank you very much!